# Two column mx, wraps at 981px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It shouldn't be wrapping at this size. The toggle menu is at 765, but the header does collpase. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Here's the site: http://snibos.com/

Comment: It doesn't look like that link is working. What you mean by "two column mx"? Also, it would help if you shared some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you should use `col-sm-6` instead of `col-md-6` in the header.